# VB6 + how to switch between windows/frame in form by buttons

Tags: vb6

I am very new beginner with VB6 and I hope I explain the things right

I want to create form with 2 buttons (the buttons are located on the top form position )
So each button will switch to other form/window/frame

For example

The first button will show window 1 (there I can set only parameters)

The second button will show window 2 (there I can set only IP address)

Please advice if we can do that by VB6 ? 
And if yes how to do that ( step by step )

Remark - Similar example but with multiple windows in the same form is the **system properties** ( right click on my computer and properties ) , the we can see each button will view different window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a form with 2 buttons, `Command1` and `Command2`.

On this form, create 2 frames, `Frame1` and `Frame2`. hide Frame2 and make sure to line up both framesso that they are of the same size and located right on top of each other (`Top`, `Left`, `Width` and `Height` properties must be the same)

Now put this code in:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Frame1.Visible = True
    Frame2.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Frame1.Visible = False
    Frame2.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Now each the first button shows the first frame while hiding the 2nd. The second button hides the first frame and shows the seconds. I think this is the simplest way to implement your task.

PS: don't forget to name your objects properly, it's not a good idea to have default names like `Command1` or `Frame2` - should be more descriptive than that.

Comment: this is the best solution that I have seen

Comment: Just keep in mind that my approach is the simplest approach per your request, but not necessarily right one. In any business environment you shouldn't use this approach as it is hard to maintain: you can't see content of one of the frames in the design mode. The tabbed object mentioned by G Mastros or the MDI forms approach by Tony Lechner are more proper implementations.

Comment: Another limitation of this approach is that VB6 has a limit of 255 objects on the same Form, so my approach and perhaps the tabbed approach will be limited here (labels, textboxes, frames, these are all separate objects). I've encountered this limitation long time ago, but it may have been addressed since. MDI approach will not be affected because each "frame" could be designed as a separate MDI form.

Comment: what you mean about - "you can't see content of one of the frames in the design mode" , I already test it and I can see in the two frames all buttons and all check box ... etc so I not see here any problem

Comment: I also intend to creat screen in the frame , so the target will be to see runing installation from the screen , so do you think your approach is good for this task ?

Comment: "you can't see content of one of the frames in the design mode" - the design mode is the VB6 environment where you code your app. Basically, lets say you need to add a new text box to both frames, one frame is visible, but the other is below the first one (remember you had to set the TOP, BOTTOM properties to match?). So you would have to drag the top frame away, put the text box there, drag the top frame back on top of the frame... its a hassle.

Comment: "I also intend to creat screen in the frame , so the target will be to see runing installation from the screen , so do you think your approach is good for this task " - I am sorry, I don't understand what you are saying here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46378/discussion-between-eytan-and-george)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are asking about the tabbed dialog control.  To use a tabbed dialog control in VB6:

1. Click Project -> Components
2. Scroll down to "Microsoft Tabbed Dialog Control 6.0" and select it.
3. Click the Apply button.

You should notice a new control in the component tool box.  If you do not see the toolbox, click View -> ToolBox.  This is the same area of the IDE where you first click to add a button to a form.  The tabbed dialog control looks like the top tab of several file folders.  When you hover your mouse over the control in the toolbox, you will see a tool tip text of "SSTab". Click this control and then draw a rectangle on your form.

By default, this will add a tabbed dialog control with 3 tabs, but you can change this in the properties window.  You can now create any control on top of a tab of the tabbed dialog control and interact with the control exactly the same way you would if the control was placed on the form itself.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called an MDI Form. It's a form that contains other forms.

You can find a full tutorial on them [here](http://www.vbtutes.com/2013/01/mdi-forms.html), but here's the gist of what you want to do:

1. Set the *"MDIChild"* property of all your subforms you want to use to True. Disable their minimize, maximize, and resize functions as well.
2. Create an MDIForm. Disable its *AutoShowChildren* property.
3. Add a toolbar to the MDIForm. Add buttons to the toolbar corresponding to the forms you'll be switching between.
4. Implement each button's click event, to create child form as expected (or switch to an existing one).

Comment: do you think its complicated for the first VB6 beginners?

Comment: do you have example in youtube for MDI?

Comment: In my opinion MDI forms are not beginner-friendly

Comment: @George is probably right. If OP doesn't mind the visible tabs, as opposed to the buttons he specified, the tabbed interface answer is probably best.

Comment: +1 - this is my favorite and most complicated approach. But its best in terms of versatility and scaling in a business environment.